# Check if there's been data copied/pasted from a excel file (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Im going to start by telling what my intention was with this code

In my job we have to open every sales order that will be sent in that day and check for the itens to be shipped manually.
Since its very time consuming i tought in creating a worksheet that it will look for the itens in every sales order and copy/paste in my master so i can know what i need to get.

However to my sheet works I had to make a few changes in the Sales order, but now I want to create a error check, that if the file that it was open was an older SO it will tell me its order number so later i can check it.
Also i want to check if by some reason nothing was found in that SO.

**Now ill explain what my code does** (I have a little knowledge in coding and in excel vba, so please dont judge my ugly script)

Using the value of a cell in a range, it will open the folder and file that matches it's value, then will look for a specific range and for a specific cell value, in this case "Perfil", if this value is found it will copy some cells.

After looking for that file it will open another one and do the same.

However if "Perfil" is not found it wont copy and paste anything and it will just go to the next file.

```
Public Sub test()
On Error GoTo Errormsg

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Fonte As Workbook
Dim Dest As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Arquivo As String
Dim Path As String
Dim celula As Range
Dim cll As Range
Dim Inicio As Range
Dim Fim As Range
Dim OffInicio As Range
Dim OffFim As Range
Dim busca As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Dest = Workbooks("testee.xlsm")
Path = 'My file path

lrow = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each celula In Dest.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:A" & lrow)

    Dest.Sheets(1).Activate
    Pedido = Cells(celula.Row, 1)
    FolderName = Pedido & "*"
    Arquivo = "\" & Pedido

    Folder = Dir(Path & FolderName, vbDirectory)
    Filename = Dir(Path & Folder & Arquivo & "*.xlsx")

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Folder & "\" & Filename, 0)
    Set Fonte = Workbooks(Filename)

    Fonte.Activate


    Set Inicio = Fonte.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="MODO DE FIXAÇÃO DO PRODUTO")
    Set Fim = Fonte.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="OBSERVAÇÕES")
    Set OffInicio = Inicio.Offset(1, 0)
    Set OffFim = Fim.Offset(-1, 1)
    Set busca = Range(OffInicio, OffFim).Columns(5)
    Set check = Range(OffInicio, OffFim).Columns(9)

        Range(OffInicio, OffFim).Columns(5).Select

        Set busca = Selection

    For Each cl In busca
        tipo = Cells(cl.Row, 5).Value

        If tipo = "Perfil" Then

        tamanho = Cells(cl.Row, 6).Value
        expessura = Cells(cl.Row, 11).Value
        cor = Cells(cl.Row, 12).Value

        lrow2 = Dest.Sheets(2).Range("D" & Dest.Sheets(2).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        linha = lrow2 + 1

        Dest.Sheets(2).Range("D" & linha).Value = Pedido
        Dest.Sheets(2).Range("E" & linha).Value = tamanho
        Dest.Sheets(2).Range("H" & linha).Value = cor

        End If
Next cl

End If

Next celula

Errormsg:
lrow2 = Dest.Sheets(2).Range("D" & Dest.Sheets(2).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
linha = lrow2 + 1

Dest.Sheets(2).Range("D" & linha).Value = Pedido
Dest.Sheets(2).Range("E" & linha).Value = "Pedido com modelo Antigo"

End Sub
```

I want to know the files that no data has been copied, so I can check manually and see why it wasnt.
To do that i tought in checking if in that file any data has been copied and pasted in my master sheet, if nothing was done it will send a message in a cell telling its number so i can check it later.

**Now is my question:**
I dont know if is possible to check if anything was pasted from that file, in case is possible, how i do that?

I cant just check if "Perfil" exists because for my sheet works I had to change a few things in the sheets that had the data I needed, and "perfil"is not something that the older version of it had.

Also in my new version "Perfil"is not the only value that the column can have so i cant just check if perfil is not found there.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear to me what's your actual question

Comment: You cound just write `Else Debug.Print Dest.Name` and after it has run all workbooks that were not copied are listed in the console

Comment: @DisplayName I've eddited my question so i can make it more clear, but anyway what i want to know if is possible to check if anything was copied and pasted from a file, if is possible how can i do it

Comment: @FloLie I cant just use else because "Profile" is not the only value that the range can have, it could be other thing as well empty, thats why i tought in checking if anything was pasted

Comment: to "check if anything was pasted"... so you want to capture worksheet changes?

Comment: @ashleedawg If copy/paste is saved as worksheet change and is possible to identify only those, then yes

Comment: @aidos - I assume that whatever you're pasting is changing the worksheet.  (That's generally the purpose of pasting, anyhow!)

Comment: @ashleedawg i can try this, can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @aidos With the answer below, you can use `wksChanged ` to determine whether the worksheet has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can check if anything has changed in the workbook.  I'd suggest this method:

In any (new or existing) **standard** module, add a public variable declaration at or near the top of the module:

```
Public wksChanged As Boolean
```

For each worksheet that you want to monitor for changes, open the Worksheet's module by **right-clicking** the **worksheet's tab** and clicking `View Code`:

[image: img]

...and then add this procedure (to *each* applicable worksheet module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    wksChanged = True
End Sub
```

`wksChanged` will default to `False` when the workbook is first opened, and **will change to `True` when any cell is changed**.  You can "reset" it at any time with:

```
wksChanged = False
```